# How to convert empty list to None value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to check if list is empty or Not if empty i need to pass `None` . I need to extract values from the dictionary

Below is my output of dictionary

```
    d = {
        'Business': []   
    }
```

I am extracting the values from the dictionary for so many ids. I just need `None` to added to list if list is Null

Expected out is is like below since I could not find any values corresponds to Business Key

```
    d = {
        'Business': [None],
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension like this -

```
{ k: v or [None]  for k, v in d.items()}
```

O/P: `{'Business': [None]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
parsed_dict = {key : None if not value else value for key, value in output_dict.items()}
```

Comment: Using your idea, I think this code fits a bit more his thoughts
`d = {key:[None] if value==[] else value for key, value in d.items()}`

Comment: by the way you can easily do it recursively if you have another dictionary (or list) in the list of values

Answer (score 0):

You can convert like this:

```
if d['Business']==[]:
   d['Business'].append(None)
```

Comment: Adding a quick explanation with this code sample can help improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if value == []:
        d[key] = None
```

Comment: Adding a quick explanation with this code sample can help improve this answer.